# Help in designing a small Unit Test Macro in Clojure

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, clojure

I have a small unit test macro

```
  (defmacro is [expr value]
        `(if (= ~expr ~value)
             'yes
             (println "Expected " ~value "In" ~expr "But Evaluated to" ~expr)))
```

How do I correctly write the error message?
Right now it gives

```
Clojure 1.0.0-
1:1 user=> (is (+ 2 2) 4)
user/yes
1:2 user=> (is (+ 2 2) 5)
Expected  5 In 4 But Evaluated to 4
```

I want to evaluate the expression and say 'yes if the evaluated value matches expected else
print the error with the *unevaluated expression* instead of the value after "In".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Original Answer**

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
(defmacro is [expr value]
    `(if (= ~expr ~value)
         true
         (println "Expected " ~value "In" (str (quote ~expr)) 
                  "But Evaluated to" ~expr)))
```

what `(quote ~expr)` does is bring the s-expression represented by `expr` into your "template", but prevents it from being evaluated, then applying `str` to the unevaluated s-expression makes it into a string for concatenation with the other strings of the error message. So, :

```
user=> (is (+ 2 2) 5)
Expected  5 In (+ 2 2) But Evaluated to 4
```

produces the desired behavior.

Rather than using `'yes` to report success, you can simply use `true` as the report for the success of the test, giving:

```
user=> (is (+ 2 2) 4)
true
```

and avoiding the problem of `'yes` being returned as a qualified symbol. If you need a symbol for some reason, then you could make a keyword:

```
(defmacro is [expr value]
    `(if (= ~expr ~value)
         :yes
         (println "Expected " ~value "In" (str (quote ~expr)) 
                  "But Evaluated to" ~expr)))


user=> (is (+ 2 2) 4)
:yes
```

**Answer to Question Asked in Comments**

You asked in comments:

> I am sorry I should have been clearer in my question. What would be the difference between a symbol and keyword in this case?

Consider your original definition (with the correction to make the error return the way you wanted):

```
(defmacro is [expr value]
`(if (= ~expr ~value)
     'yes
     (println "Expected " ~value "In" (str (quote ~expr)) 
              "But Evaluated to" ~expr)))
```

I imagine that you want the `'yes` thinking that you could use to test against `'yes` in other contexts (one often sees these types of tests in introductory lisp texts). But `'yes` is used in your macro definition, it returns a qualified symbol when the test is passes:

```
user=> (is (+ 2 2) 4)
user/yes
```

Now, this is not what you would want. Imagine that you said this:

```
user=> (= 'yes (is (+ 2 2) 4))
false
```

To get a `true` answer, you would have to say this (using a syntax quote):

```
user=> (= `yes (is (+ 2 2) 4))
true
```

If you defined your macro to return `:yes`, then you get the checkable return without having to syntax quote the object you are using to do the checking:

```
user=> (= :yes (is (+ 2 2) 4))
true
```

But this is all superfluous because you are really interested in whether `(+ 2 2)` returns `4`, i.e. whether your assertion is `true` or `false` rather than whether `'yes` equals ``yes`or`'yes`; you can just have it return`true` and avoid this checking step (in the real world).

In any case, to understand what qualified symbols are, you need to read the [docs on the clojure reader](http://clojure.org/reader) and [this SO answer explaining the ins and outs of symbols in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175920/explain-clojure-symbols).

Comment: Thanks. But Why did you make it a keyword? What would be the difference?

Comment: The problem with the quoted symbol is that it comes out as a qualified symbol, as you noted. I suggested using 'true' as the best replacement, but threw out the option of using a keyword if, for some reason, you needed something 'symbolike' for reasons having to do the way you've written the rest of the program. I think, though, that 'true' is the way to go in the abstract.

Comment: I am sorry I should have been clearer in my question. What would be the difference between a symbol and keyword in this case?

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks a Lot. I wish I could upvote the answer more.

Comment: Note that 'value' is evaluated twice. It's better to wrap it with a gensym.

Answer (score 0):

You have a crosscutting concern when you have the 'Is' macro print. Have the 'Is' macro return a list that contains something like this (:pass form actual-answer expected-answer) or (:fail form actual-answer expected-answer). You probably have a DefTest macro for aggregating your asserts. That is where you should pp your answer.